# Bootstrap,having trouble placing my image and text side by side in 3 sets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having trouble placing my images directly on the left of each set of text, the text keeps displaying below the image. Im using the col-md-4 so ill have 3 sets of each text and image.

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--Row with three equal columns-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="demo-content">

        <p>
          <img src="images/squareicon.png">
          <h3>Versatile Spaces</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="demo-content bg-alt">
        <img src="images/pointericon.png">
        <h3>Central Location</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="demo-content">
        <img src="images/foodicon.png">
        <h3>Catering to Taste</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Float the images to the left: `.demo-content img { float:left; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Bootstrap you can add the class `pull-left` on the image or change the HTML to something like this.

```
<img src="images/pointericon.png">
<h3>Central Location</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
```

To something like

```
<div class="col-xs-4"><img src="images/pointericon.png"></div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
<h3>Central Location</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p></div>
```

Not a complete example, but the text is going below because heading elements are full width block elements. A block element will not push up against anything unless it's floated. In my mind, changing the HTML is better as you can then control if it's stacked on mobile and/or side by side on larger screen sizes. Also allows you to use the `img-responsive` class if you want. Simply floating the image restricts your options a bit.

This works and has spaces. 100% bootstrap no floating the image:

```
<div class="container">
  <!--Row with three equal columns-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="demo-content row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img src="//placehold.it/120">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <h3>Versatile Spaces</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 row">
      <div class="demo-content bg-alt">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img src="//placehold.it/120">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <h3>Versatile Spaces</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="demo-content row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img src="//placehold.it/120">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <h3>Versatile Spaces</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the example but still displaying in stacked form rather then side by side, is there a way to bring them closer together in bootstrap so they all fit properly?

Comment: i just tried the pull-left and it worked placing them side by side, now how would i put space between the image and the text?

Comment: @Leeish that works out great, now i need to place some spacing between the image and the text that are side by side, how would i accomplish that?

Comment: One way is to add padding-left on the `col-xs-8` that wraps the text. You could alter the column sizes and add a spacer one. So have a 4-1-7 instead of a 4-8. You could wrap the text and add padding to the wrapper. There are numerous ways it's CSS. Your original question is answered. If you have another create another question.